# Should development server's configuration be the same with the production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been learning about AWS to deploy my rails application. It seems AWS Beanstalk is the easiest one I can use for my deployment. It even provides CLI tool so that I may be able to deploy easily as I do in Heroku.

But what I haven't still figured out is whether my development server's configuration should be the same with the production server which is a AWS Beanstalk stack.

For example, is it possible to use a different OS between the development server and production server? Ruby, MySQL, Web server and all other stuffs should be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Using identical configuration (especially operating systems and software) isn't a hard requirement, it is a recommendation.

It might often happen that some code doesn't run on your production environment but works perfectly on your development machine because of some underlying incompatibility in your code or your libraries with your production stack. This could be avoided if you used the same software on your dev machine.

As for your question, it is possible to use different OSes or software versions on your dev/prod servers, but this is highly unrecommended.

Comment: Then is it recommended to use the same configuration that the beanstalk is using? Do I have to configure my development server the same way the beanstalk is?

Comment: @SookieJ beanstalk runs Ruby 2.1.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. Here's their full config for rails apps: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

Comment: Thanks. I am now setting up my dev server all over again to make it the same with the production server.